# Can python be used reliably as a ETH miner?

Tags: ether, mining, python, ethash

Was wondering if python can be used reliably as a ETH miner?

Searching around etherminer and others are made in C/C++

Answer (score 0):

From a development standpoint, Python has fewer keywords than C and C++. Python also has an easier syntax whereas C is more difficult to write.

But from a performance standpoint, Python is slower than C as it takes significant CPU time for interpretation. So, speed-wise C is a better option.

You can imagine that this is important in a miner that would like fast processing and as much jobs as possible during a certain time period. But either way, it is possible and reliable, maybe just not that optimal